# Why `as` keyword is not casting in this code

Tags: casting, vala

`as` keyword is used in Vala for casting as mentioned on [this page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Syntax).

I see it being used in following code on [this page](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.FileInputStream.html):

```
FileOutputStream os = ios.output_stream as FileOutputStream;
```

However, it is not working in following code:

```
void main(){
    string ss = "5";
    stdout.printf("string ss = %s \n", ss);

    int i = ss as int; 
    stdout.printf("int i = %d \n", i); 
}
```

The error is:

```
$ valac mycode.vala
mycode.vala:6.10-6.18: error: Operation not supported for this type
    int i = ss as int; 
            ^^^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Even integer cannot be casted to float:

```
void main(){
    int i = 5;
    stdout.printf("int i = %d \n", i);

    float f = i as float; 
    stdout.printf("int f = %f \n", f); 
}
```

Error is:

```
mycode.vala:6.12-6.22: error: Operation not supported for this type
    float f = i as float; 
              ^^^^^^^^^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vala has two types of casting: static and dynamic type casting.

Static casting (https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Static_Type_Casting) is done with parenthesis as in other languages like C:

```
int i = 5;
float f = (float) i;
```

Dynamic casting (https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Dynamic_Type_Casting) is done with the `as` operator and only works on class types (OOP):

```
Widget w = new Button();
Button button = w as Button;
```

When a dynamic cast fails (because the object is not compatible with the target type) the result will be `null`.

In addition you can parse data (https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Strings), for example this will convert a string into an integer:

```
string s = "5";
int i = int.parse(s);
```

The other way around there is a neat feature called string interpolation:

```
int i = 5;
string s = @"$i";
```

Under the hood this just calls the `to_string()` method:

```
int i = 5;
string s = i.to_string();
```

Comment: Very well explained.  What is `(!)` mentioned amongst cast operators (in  addition to `(type)` and `as`) on https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Syntax

Comment: I have never seen this, but it might something like C# null-forgiving operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving

Comment: Vala also has a strict non-null mode btw. The question mark operator is used for optional value types that can accept null.